# What is meant by no wireless extension?

Tags: networking, wireless, interface, wireless-access-point

Whenever I type **iwconfig**. Some of the network interface cards show **no wireless extension**. What does it possibly mean ?

Comment: It means that some of your network cards are not WiFi cards. If you have an ordinary Ethernet (i.e. cabled) network card, it would show up as having no wireless extension. Only your WiFi card(s) would give details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in the 1990s, there wasn't much of a standard about how the operating system and those new-fangled wireless networking devices were supposed to interact. Because of that, the operating system needed to "talk" to every device in a "different language", so to speak. Often, that was even true for different variations of the same device. So people needed to develop separate drivers for each and every wireless networking device.

At some point, a developer named Jean Tourrilhes decided to develop an interface, an API. With that, the operating system could address any wireless networking device (or at least, *many* devices) in an uniform manner. The API would then handle how the specific device would like to be "talked to". This API was named [Wireless Extensions](https://hewlettpackard.github.io/wireless-tools/Linux.Wireless.Extensions.html):

> It all started when I tried to install a Wavelan network on Linux computers. I was having a ISA and a PCMCIA versions of the Wavelan, and the two drivers were using totally different methods for the setup and collection of statistics (and in fact fairly incomplete...). (...) I decided to define a wireless API which would allow the user to manipulate any wireless networking device in a standard and uniform way.

So, if `iwconfig` tells you there are "no wireless extensions" for a specific device, it means that this specific device cannot be addressed via the Wireless Extensions API. This may be because the device isn't a wireless device, but a wire-bound device. This may be because the device is "virtual", like for example the loopback device. Or it may be because the wireless device in question isn't compatible with the Wireless Extensions API.

The Wireless Extensions API [isn't being developed any more](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/Wireless-Extensions#is_we_being_further_developed), but it's superseded by newer approaches. So maybe your wireless networking device isn't "covered" by the WE API, but will work with one of those newer technologies (and a different tool than `iwconfig`).

Answer (score 0):

this means those devices can't be configured with `iwconfig`, which is for devices with a wireless extension. In case you want to list details on all network devices, maybe `ip a` or its predecessor `ifconfig` is what you're looking for?

```
man iwconfig
```

```
IWCONFIG(8)                                           Linux Programmer's Manual                                          IWCONFIG(8)

NAME
       iwconfig - configure a wireless network interface
DESCRIPTION
       Iwconfig is similar to ifconfig(8), but is dedicated to the wireless interfaces. It is used to set the parameters of the net‐
       work interface which are specific to the wireless operation (for example : the frequency).  Iwconfig may also be used to dis‐
       play those parameters, and the wireless statistics (extracted from /proc/net/wireless).

       All  these  parameters  and statistics are device dependent. Each driver will provide only some of them depending on hardware
       support, and the range of values may change. Please refer to the man page of each device for details.
```